# How can add Navbar with maps in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I want to add same bar to my map page top. But I couldnt find a way to add ?
[image: My code]
[image: What I want to do]
[image: What I have]

Comment: please do NOT post code or errors as images

Answer (score 0):

User `NavgationPage` instead `ContentPage` and set `TitleView`

```
<NavigationPage.TitleView>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Source="logo.png" />
        <Label Text="myTitle" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
    </StackLayout>
</NavigationPage.TitleView>
```

Comment: I couldnt change because of map. When I change content page it gives an error